# Powerwise: Is it better to use console or windows GUI application in C#(.NET)?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, console

If we are writing about power-wise option - is using a console-based application in C#(.NET)  better than having Windows GUI and what's the real difference expept few libraries loaded in operational memory?

The issue is about text comparisons and working with strings, connecting to Internet, gathering data, working with database.

I meant power-capability, but as I've read here, it's more about controls than any power-relation. Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems that you want to write an HTML scraping software or some kind of web spider. I think your decision whether to write a GUI or a command line application should depend on who (users) or which other software components will use or integrate your program.

If there is no user interaction involved, I guess it would be just fine to write it as command line program. If you have some options to set you could pass them as arguments.

If it will be a recurring, isolated job, you could also consider writing the application as **windows service**, which could start with the machine.

Comment: you kind of got my point. It'd be application to check plagiarism - comparing documents with internet resource and database.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your requirements are. GUIs tend to be harder to write than console apps, but open up a great level of usability (if you design them well, which is another matter entirely).

If it's a simple tool that doesn't really need interactivity: start with some command line arguments, process and report progress, finish - then I'd write a console app. If more interactivity is required, go for a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

A software without GUI will have many extra clock available.  It takes resources to display a GUI...  On today computer, a simple GUI will not really affect the performance.

If you looking for have the better computation power, having a multi-thread architecture should give you a lot more power that console vs GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in what you can do with the things you mentioned (strings, internet, database). The difference between console and GUI apps is solely in how you interact with the user. Everything else is the same.

If you meant power consumption instead, then I'm afraid I misunderstood your question.

Comment: So do GUI applications cause greater power consumption since it requires more things to be used?